# Change valueField config on Ext-JS combobox?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, combobox, config

I have a combobox on a form where I need to reset its store along with the 'displayField' and 'valueField' configs.

Resetting the store via `cmb.bindStore(newStore)` works great.

Setting `cmb.displayField = 'newfieldname';` also works great.

However, `cmb.valueField = 'newValField';` does not work.  The combo displays the right stuff, but when i select an item, the value is using the old valueField value, not the new one.

I've tried:

- doing a `cmb.reset()` afterwards
- `Ext.apply(...)`

Is it because `valueField` is somehow special because it is a required field?  Is there some special way to set a config value on an Ext-JS component I don't know about or is it just not possible to change the value of 'valueField'?

FYI - Here is my code:

```
    comp.bindStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields : [ {
            name : 'abbr',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'name',
            type : 'string'
        }, {
            name : 'slogan',
            type : 'string'
        } ],
        data : [ {
            "abbr" : "AL",
            "name" : "Alabama",
            "slogan" : "The Heart of Dixie"
        }, {
            "abbr" : "AK",
            "name" : "Alaska",
            "slogan" : "The Land of the Midnight Sun"
        }, {
            "abbr" : "AZ",
            "name" : "Arizona",
            "slogan" : "The Grand Canyon State"
        }, {
            "abbr" : "AR",
            "name" : "Arkansas",
            "slogan" : "The Natural State"
        }, ]
    }));

    comp.displayField = 'abbr';    // THIS WORKS
    comp.valueField = 'abbr';      // THIS DOESNT WORK
```

Comment: Are you using `getValue`?  I ran your code with the Ext example with the valueField of 'name' and `getValue` worked.

Comment: Did you run it with `valueField` and `displayField` being `'name'` first?  If I do that, and then change valueField and displayField to be 'abbr' the pull down lists shows abbreviations, but when you select one, the name of the state ends up being displayed in the combo box.  I'll try to find time to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I did it from the example which had a `tpl`and `displayTpl`  and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there but you where looking at the wrong property cause `valueField` is not your issue, it is `displayField`. Your exact problem are preconfigured and cached properties. The first is the display template the second is the picker instance. You need to override the template and remove the picker instance. Here's a working snipped (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/41/)**)

In the example I added a second trigger with a cross. Hit it and the ComboBox get the new values. I recommend you to create your own component for this by extending from ComboBox and wrap all into a reconfigure method that would expect tree parameters.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // The data store containing the list of states
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data : [
            {"abbr":"AL1", "name":"Alabama1"},
            {"abbr":"AK1", "name":"Alaska1"},
            {"abbr":"AZ1", "name":"Arizona1"}
            //...
        ]
    });

    var comp = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        id: 'combo-ident',
        trigger2Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
        onTrigger2Click: function (args) {
            var comp = Ext.getCmp('combo-ident');
            comp.clearValue();
            comp.bindStore(Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields : [ {
                    name : 'abbr',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    name : 'name',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    name : 'slogan',
                    type : 'string'
                } ],
                data : [ {
                    "abbr" : "AL",
                    "name" : "Alabama",
                    "slogan" : "The Heart of Dixie"
                }, {
                    "abbr" : "AK",
                    "name" : "Alaska",
                    "slogan" : "The Land of the Midnight Sun"
                }, {
                    "abbr" : "AZ",
                    "name" : "Arizona",
                    "slogan" : "The Grand Canyon State"
                }, {
                    "abbr" : "AR",
                    "name" : "Arkansas",
                    "slogan" : "The Natural State"
                }, ]
            }));

            comp.displayField = 'abbr';
            comp.valueField = 'name';
            comp.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl for=".">' +
                    '{[typeof values === "string" ? values : values["' + comp.displayField + '"]]}' +
                    '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">' + comp.delimiter + '</tpl>' +
                '</tpl>'
            );
            comp.picker = null;
        },
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    comp.on('select', function(){ console.log(arguments); console.log(arguments[0].getSubmitValue()); })

});
```

Comment: Your answer is right on the money...and thanks for the JSFiddle.  a couple follow-up questions out of curiosity:  Why isn't there a setter for every config in extjs that does the Right Thing?  How on earth was I supposed to ever figure this out without help from someone like you?  It's like hidden tribal knowledge...

Comment: Hi @HDave and thanks for accepting :) Now to your question; Well, I guess the point here is the amount of initialisation that happens here and in addition I think you don't had a common problem. See the reconfigure function on the grid. This was sort of common need and got therefore implemented. I think the important point is that once you a grip on the framework you can customize nearly everything. But you will just find common use in the API, for the rest you have to look under the hood (at the source). But I must admit yes for some things you will need bits of tribal knowledge ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible to reconfigure the combo box this way, but perhaps you can create another combobox with a different store and valueField. Hide/destroy one or the other based on your logic.