# How to change "valueField" of extjs Combobox from controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am totally new to Extjs, Following is part of structure of my app

View  -  contain combobox

```
                xtype: 'combobox',
                itemId: 'myCombo',
                fieldLabel: 'myLabel',
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
                    fields: [{
                            name: 'key1'
                        }, {
                            name: 'key2'
                        }],
                    storeId: 'myStore',
                    autoLoad: false
                }),
                displayField: 'key1',
                valueField: 'key2',
```

Controller  -  Contain reference to combobox

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.myController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['MyApp.view.MyView'],
refs: [{
        ref: 'myComboRef',
        selector: '#myCombo'
    }],
this.control({
        '#myCombo': {
            change: this.getData
}),
.
.
.
getData: function(currFeild, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
    // I can get "valueField" of myCombo by
    var valueFieldData = this.getMyComboRef().valueField;

   // I want to change "valueField" to "key3"
   // ????????
});
```

So can anybody please tell me, how can I set new valueField for "myCombo" ?

I already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591063/change-valuefield-config-on-ext-js-combobox) link. But, it didn't helped much

Comment: sry, though why u want to change your valuefield? mby im just too blind - though i cant imagine a case where i do want that.

Comment: In my app there can be multiple "valueField" for a single combo....   And I was unable to handle it in view only. So I am looking for changing it through Controller..

If you know any other good approach then please suggest me

Comment: What you mean by multiple valueField? Usually you got a store of models where your model has an id property. and that id prop should be your value field cuz u can identify the exact record with it. So you dont have such a field with which u can identify the record?

Comment: Do you just want to retrieve a different value (so not key2) when the change event is fired?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is a good solution to change the `valueField` of a combo. Though i can do this via `comob.valueField = 'newValueField';` e.g. in your change event handler. Though the `getValue()` fn will show the value of your new value field only the next time you change a value. So i dont think this is a good approach.

The `valueField` should be a field which identifies your records in the store and should usually not be changed. If you need to access other fields of your selected record you can get the selected record of the store and then access the field you want.

e.g. in your change event handler:

```
change: function(cmp, newValue){  
    var record = cmp.store.findRecord(cmp.valueField, newValue);    
    var field2Value = record.get('field2');
    //do something with your field2Vlaue...
}
```

I have also made a fiddle for you so you can see this example in live action.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jek